# How to download file ( excel ) from api in react native?

Tags: react-native, file-upload

first of all, I'll say thank you for read this question,
I've a problem in my project, how do I download a file ( excel ) from an API ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have so many options you can use for downloading any type of files!
here i will mention two of them which you can find enough details on how to implement .

1.[RNFetchBlob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#download-example-fetch-files-that-need-authorization-token)

2.[RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

if you use the 2nd options you need to fetch your datas first and with rnfs you are able to write to your device!